# bash replace newlines into quotes

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I've the following CSV file:

```
"test","test2","test
3 and some other

data"
"test4","test5","test6 and some other


data"
```

I would like to replace all the newlines (windows or unix style) by the character `\n`, so I would obtain:

```
"test","test2","test\n3 and some other\n\ndata"
"test4","test5","test6 and some other\n\n\ndata"
```

I've tried with `awk` but without success:

```bash
cat myFile.csv | awk -F \" -v OFS=\" '{
   for (i=0; i<NF; i++) {
      gsub("\\n", "\\\\n", $i)
   }
   print
}'
```

Comment: You can do it by replacing `\([^"]\)\n\(.\)` by `\1\\n\2`  (using Perl, for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
$ awk '!/"$/{sub(/$/,"\\n");printf "%s",$0;next}1' file
"test","test2","test\n3 and some other\n\ndata"
"test4","test5","test6 and some other\n\n\ndata"
```

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you? two lines with same idea

```
awk -v RS="\0"  '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n");sub(/\\n$/,"");gsub(/"\\n"/,"\"\n\"");}1' file
```

or

```
awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n");sub(/\\n$/,"\n");gsub(/"\\n"/,"\"\n\"")}1' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  cat file
"test","test2","test
3 and some other

data"
"test4","test5","test6 and some other


data"
```

output:

```
kent$  awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" '{gsub(/\n/,"\\n");sub(/\\n$/,"\n");gsub(/"\\n"/,"\"\n\"")}1' file
"test","test2","test\n3 and some other\n\ndata"
"test4","test5","test6 and some other\n\n\ndata"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/^("[^"]*",?){3}$/!{$!N;s/\n/\\n/;ta};P;D' file
```

or at a pinch:

```
 sed ':a;/"$/!{$!N;s/\n/\\n/;ta};P;D' file
```