# Unix replace new lines inside quotes

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

I am trying to figure out the below in Unix.

I have a `csv` file which is separated into columns and some of the columns have some text with new line characters. Usually the text starts and end with quotes. I would like to eliminate those new line characters between the quotes so that the text appears in one line.

For example the content looks like below:

```
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3, HEADER4
data1, data2, data3, "Text here with
new line 
characters"
```

And I would like it to be displayed like below:

```
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3, HEADER4
data1, data2, data3, "Text here with new line characters"
```

I tried to use tools like `awk` and `sed` but without much luck.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash replace newlines into quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036744/bash-replace-newlines-into-quotes)

Comment: @Mr.Llama That looks close but I tried several of the answers in that question including the accepted answer.  None worked for the OP's file.  They removed _all_ newlines and the OP only wants to remove quoted newlines.

Comment: Can your quoted text contain commas? Can it contain escaped quotes as either `\"` or `""`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and

1) the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{while ( match($0,/"[^"]+"/,a) ) {gsub(/\n/," ",a[0]); print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[0]; $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} print}' file
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3, HEADER4
data1, data2, data3, "Text here with new line characters"
```

2) the 4th arg to split():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{n=split($0,f,/"[^"]+"/,s); for (i=0; i<=n; i++) {gsub(/\n/," ",s[i]); print f[i] s[i]} }' file
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3, HEADER4
data1, data2, data3, "Text here with new line characters"
```

Answer (score 6):

The `ORS` can be toggled when the quotes within a line are unbalanced, replacing new-lines within the quoted text.  It will not work with C-style escaped quotes `\"`, but the normal style for escaping quotes in CSV files keeps them balanced `""` ([RFC4180 2.7](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)).

```
awk -F'"' 'NF&&NF%2==0{ORS=ORS==RS?" ":RS}1' file.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -r 'H;1h;$!d;x; :a; s/(, *"[^"]*)\n/\1 /; ta' file.csv
HEADER1, HEADER2, HEADER3, HEADER4
data1, data2, data3, "Text here with new line  characters"
```

The above looks for any occurrence of comma, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by one double quote, followed by anything except a double-quote, followed by a newline.  If found, it removes the newline.  This is repeated as long as such lines are found.

The above was tested under GNU sed.  For BSD sed, try:

```
sed -E -e 'H;1h;$!d;x' -e ':a' -e 's/(, *"[^"]*)\n/\1 /' -e 'ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ / if $. >= 2' file
```

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
awk 'NR >= 2{printf("%s ", $0);next} 1' file
```